# LQFP vs WLCSP a question about package methods

Tags: microcontroller

first of all, I do not have proper knowledge about the packaging methods so I am sorry If I ask more questions after your replies. I am in a model rocket project and trying to choose a microprocessor for the rocket. But I am having trouble while deciding about the package type and the pins(which is another subject that I am not sure which type I should choose). The company that I am trying to buy a processor offers different kinds of variations of one processor model. One option varies in the package type as LQFP and WLCSP. In addition to package type, they also mentioned pins such as 64-pin 72-pin 81-pin 100-pin, etc.

Now, I searched the internet for what exactly LQFP and WLCSP, learned about them. But the problem is that I cannot find information about which one of them should be used in the field rockets, or which one would be easier to assemble. These questions are also valid for pin options. I know what a pin is physically but do not know how can its amount affect the project.

If there was a chance for anyone to enlighten me about these topics, it would be marvelous. It should not have to be too specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WCLSP** -> Wafer Scale Chip Scale Package

[image: From Freescale app note: https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/AN3846.PDF]

This is advanced packaging method, which makes the PCB connections directly on the uncut wafer. In other methods, the wafer is cut into die and then the connections are made with bondwires or through an interposer. The main advantage is reduced inductance, so higher speeds are acheivable. Additionally, the package size is reduced. The "pins" are small solder blobs on the bottom, so it is impossible to solder or rework by hand - you need a reflow oven, and very good test methodology. Given the level you are at, avoid this package!

**LQFP** - Low profile quad flat package

[image]

The pins are brought out to the four edges. Reasonably easy to solder by hand, with a bit of experience.

You should choose your package only after you've determined the functionality you need. You should also consider the effort in developing and debugging your whole circuit. For example, you might buy the required microcontroller in a big, easily reworked package for development, as you'll definitely make some mistakes, need to re-route etc. Then, if required by your application, you could go to a smaller package.

The number of pins refers to how many externals inputs/outputs are available for your use. Tip: get more pins than you think you need for development. It's much easier to downsize later, than to write code to multiplex pins etc when you just want to write your code.

For your use case, really *any* package type will do fine (as long as you can solder it) - it's unlikely to the largest/heaviest part of your rocket.

Comment: You truly are a lifesaver and I just wanted you to know that the little tips are precious for someone like me who are not familiar with electronics( at least, for now) as good as an electronics engineer do, since I am an engineering physics student. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @prozgoret No problem - happy building!

Comment: Wow, they have Z80s in LQFP now?

Answer (score 2):

You are over thinking the packaging.

1. Choose the microcontroller family based on the functions that it provides in its peripherals. Most manufacturers provide a few options for packaging.
2. Draw up your circuit with a high pin count version of the microcontroller, this will show you how many pins you need. Pins are connection points between your circuit and the controller.
3. If available pick a smaller pin count version that will still connect all of your circuit input/outputs.
4. Now pick the package. If you are hand assembling avoid packages that have pins under the package. For this WLCSP is not suitable use LQFP.

Comment: Just the answer that I was looking for, again sorry I could not give more information about my project because mentioning a topic leads to another to another and I did not want to bother you that much. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

WLCSP would be difficult to hand solder - you really need to use a reflow oven to solder it. Benefits - small and lightweight. May also have sensitivity to light.

LQFP can be soldered by hand - if the pcb pads are designed such that you can apply heat to the joint easily or by using a hot air tool.

As for the number of pins - how much i/o do you need? Using a 100pin part is not only physically larger and heavier but may be more expensive. Do you need all those pins? We can't answer that as we don't know what your project is. I'd suggest if you're asking these kinds of questions, you've started at the wrong end of the problem.

Comment: I know I didnt mention necessary information for you to accurately comment about it and I am sorry about it. But just the answer you replied is totally enough and extremely useful for me. Thanks a lot for your comment.